# Checkerboard HTML List without padding <li>

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create this [checkerboard-styled social media](http://i39.tinypic.com/15gtu6g.png) with only this HTML (feel free to add classes/IDs):

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Google+</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LinkedIn</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have to create empty `<li></li>` at my own attempt, and I think the HTML is 'dirty'. Here is my last attempt that works but 'dirty':

```
<!-- html code -->
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="facebook.png" /></a></li>
    <li></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="twitter.png" /></a></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="google.png" /></a></li>
    <li></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="linkedin.png" /></a></li>
</ul>

/* stylesheet */
ul
{
list-style-type: none;
    width: 128px;
}
li
{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}
li img
{
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the [nth-child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child).

```
ul { list-style-type: none; }
li
{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}
ul :nth-child(2n)
{
    position: relative;
    top: 32px;
}
li img
{
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}
```